# What are the most general structures that admit a singular value decomposition for each element?

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I was looking at *-algebra and C*-algebra and as far as I understood, the latter guarantees each element to have a singular value decomposition, or at least, that every element $a$ is such that $u a v$ is self-adjoint for some unitary elements $u, v$.

Is there anything between these two structures (weaker than C* and stronger than *) that guarantees such claim?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true than in an arbitrary C$^*$-algebra given $a$ there exist unitaries $u,v$ such that $uav$ is selfadjoint.

For instance consider $B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ and let $a$ be the unilateral shift. Given any unitaries $u,v$ we have
$$
(uav)^*(uav)=v^*a^*u^*uav=v^*a^*av=v^*v=1, 
$$
while
$$
(uav)(uav)^*=uavv^*au^*=uaa^*u^*,
$$
which is a projection of codimension $1$. So we cannot have $(uav)^*=uav$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but then is there an axiom that we can add to a *-algebra for which that claim follows? (besides the claim itself)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the slightest idea. What kind of axiom would you expect?

Comment: I don’t know, but for example, in order to prove the spectral theorem in a involutive algebra, which axioms are we really using in the proof?

Comment: I guess it depends on the formulation, but if you want everything to happen inside your algebra, you need a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, looks like a vNa with a faithful normal trace should do the job.

Comment: Yes, in a finite von Neumann algebra you can write the polar decomposition with a unitary.